# ZF2 phprenderer & routing

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am getting

```
Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "link- 
account-manager/add-accounts/index"; resolver could not resolve to a file
```

and I'm not sure why phprender is looking in link-account-manager when I want it to be looking in linkaccount-manager. Is this a default behavior? I tried recursively searching for "link-account-manager" and there were no matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed ZF2 default behavior. You may have a look at `\Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer` and `\Zend\View\Resolver\*`.

The template resolver transforms a camel case `Module` or `Controller` (LinkAccountManager, AddAccountsController) names into a template path like `link-account-manager\add-accounts\index.phtml`.

It is possible to configure some values in the `module.config.php`:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array(
        'your-custom-template' => __DIR__ . '/../view/your-custom-template.phtml' // e.g. !!
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
        // add custom paths here
    ),
    ...
),
```

Further, you can also change the template via view models. Assuming you have your folder structure like 'linkaccount-manager\view\linkaccountmanager\' (in the default module's view folder!), e.g.:

```
namespace LinkAccountManager;

public class AddAccountsController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $viewModel = new ViewModel();
        ...
        $viewModel->setTemplate('linkaccount-manager\add-accounts\index');
        return $viewModel;
    }
}
```